# wrong printed sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, printing

I'm new to C++ and I've been doing bubbleSort, but when I want to show the numbers in the terminal, the leading number is a problem. Sorry for my bad english btw.

where am i doing wrong?

this is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void printArray(int *myArr, int lenght) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; ++i) {
        std::cout << myArr[i] << ", ";
    }
}

int bubbleSort(int *myArr, int lenght) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lenght-1; ++j) {
            if (myArr[j] > myArr[j+1]) {
                int temp = myArr[j];
                myArr[j] = myArr[j+1];
                myArr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return *myArr;
}

int main() {
    int myArr[] = {10,14,13,19,15,12,16,18,17,11};
    int newArr = bubbleSort(myArr, 8);
    printArray(&newArr, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

this is what i get:
`10, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18,`  there is no 19 and double 10s

and is there any eaiser way to get lenght of array in function? Thank you...

Comment: You can use `std::array` or a `std::vector` both keep track of their actual length.

Comment: Is it intentional that your array has 10 elements but you set length to 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing pointers with arrays with single integers.

```
int bubbleSort(int *myArr, int lenght) {
    // ... not actually that important what happens here ...
    return *myArr;
}
```

Your `bubbleSort` gets a pointer to first element of an array passed, you do some sorting and eventually you return the first element of that sorted array (return type is `int`!). This is wrong, or maybe not wrong but doesn't make much sense but the real drama will only come later...

...when here

```
 int newArr = bubbleSort(myArr, 8);
 printArray(&newArr, 8);
```

you copy that single integer returned from `bubbleSort` into `newArr` (an `int`), then take its address (still "ok") and then in `printArray` act like it points to an array which it doesn't (now it goes BooooM!).

`myArr[i]` in `printArray` is undefined behavior when `i > 0`, because `myArr` points to a single integer. It does not point to an array.

TL;DR: Do not use c-arrays. c-arrays are advanced C++, they are easy to get wrong and hard to get right. Use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays and `std::array` for compiletime sized arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is the idea that should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printArray(vector<int> arr) {
    for (auto & item : arr) 
    {
        cout << item<<' ';
    }
}

void bubbleSort(vector<int> &arr) 
{
    bool swapp = true;
    while (swapp) {
        swapp = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                arr[i] += arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i] - arr[i + 1];
                arr[i] -= arr[i + 1];
                swapp = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
void main() {
    vector<int> arr = { 10,14,13,19,15,12,16,18,17,11 };
    bubbleSort(arr);

    printArray(arr);
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon.  Please add clarification to your answer, as to how your code answers the OP's question, and highlight any changes to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is - Wrong array size (i.e. 8) is passed to bubble sort function which produces wrong answer.

Use std::vector sothat superfluous length agrument can be avoided.

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<int> & vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        ...
    }
}

bubbleSort(vec);
```

Comment: Please update your answer with a description of how your answer resolves the OP's question.  Also, pure code answers are of poor quality.  I suggest only supplying minimum code so that the OP has to think about the rest of the answer.